# jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am making a jquery plugin.

You are given an object which contains several divs.

is there anyway to select the say, 3rd child div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - remember it is 0 based

e.g for the third div in an object containing a list of elements

```
$someObject.find('div:eq(2)')
```

Answer (score 1):

[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) A zero-based integer indicating which element to retrieve.

```
($('div').get(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the third div:

```
$('div').eq(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can give them a className and use each or simple select the div, and count your selections

```
var n = 0    
$("div div").each(function() {
      n++;
      if(n == 3){
            $(this).html("do your thing");
      }
});
```